# SQL Server : match is not found for contain record with combination 93&5jq issue occurs on SQL Server 2014 and 2017

Tags: sql, contains, sql-server-2017

I have a record with the following data

```
'93 SOP BOW  WOLLLEY COLLIERY VILLoge  SARNELEY  S75 5JQ'
```

```
select * 
from stpI 
where contains(dbo.stpI.S_ADDRESS, '93 & 5JQ')
```

A match isn't found.

If I use the following a match is found:

```
select * 
from stpI 
where contains(dbo.stpI.S_ADDRESS, 'S75 & 5JQ')
```

If I use the following a record isn't found:

```
select * 
from stpI 
where contains(dbo.stpI.S_ADDRESS, '93 & 5JQ')
```

It seems a number and then 5jq follows it does not return results.

Other combinations of numbers and text are found.

Using the below, records are found.

```
select * 
from stpI 
where contains(dbo.stpI.S_ADDRESS, 'S75 & 5JQ')
  and S_ADDRESS like '93%'
```

Any idea?

The issue is not to do with data lengths as bigger records columns are returned where the criteria are different.

Comment: What is your database platform?  It's presumably a matter of interpretation of the second parameter (containing your search string), but the solution may different depending on your actual database platform

Comment: `CONTAINS` is only for use with Full Text indexing for performing _loose_ textual matches, it is not intended for exact character-based matches (i.e. `CONTAINS` in T-SQL is **nothing like** `String.Contains` in C# or Java). You should use `CHARINDEX` or `LIKE` instead.

Comment: Seems like this would be a reasonable spot for `LIKE`. `SELECT * FROM stpI WHERE stpI.S_ADDRESS LIKE '93 % 5JQ'`

Comment: It does not make sense why its not matching, other results are found with other characters.

Comment: @Junior It doesn't match because `CONTAINS` does not do exact matching, and it ignores things like symbols and punctuation. Change your query to remove `CONTAINS()` and use `CHARINDEX` or `LIKE` instead.